# Outlook adds `<span style='color:blue'>` to HTML links

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto, add-in

I am creating an Outlook add-in using C# that searches for a link in an HTML (new) email body signature when a user clicks on Send button in Outlook email. I am hooking into Application_ItemSend event. What's odd is that on my machine running XP/Outlook 2007 and in another Win7/Outlook 2007 machine, I am able to search for the link in the signature with no problems. But on some other Win7/Outlook 2007 machine, I am not able to search for the link because an additional span element is being inserted by Outlook.

For example, I am searching for `<a href="http://www.google.com">`Link`</a>` in an HTML (new) email body. The link above is being inserted by a default signature so I am expecting to find it all the time. On some machines I am able to, on some machines I am not able to because the link appears like this:
`<a href="http://www.google.com"><span style='color:blue'>`Link`</span></a>`
I've rolled out a standard signature html file so the signatures for all machines are the same, but the issue still persists. I am still in the process of comparing the font/theme settings, but so far have seen no difference.

Does anyone have an idea on what's happening here?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure but you could try checking IE's link color settings (Internet Options->Colors). Of course your problem can be solved by parsing the HTML rather than searching it as text.

Comment: To add more context, the goal of the add-in is to replace a text (in this case, a link) in an outgoing mail signature with another set of text (in this case another link, with some images). So the original link in the signature acts as a token that needs to be replaced. I don't see how parsing makes any difference. Unless I'm completely missing something obvious. Thanks.

Comment: I was just thinking that you could parse out all the links and find the one with text of "Link", ignoring other tags in it, then just replace the whole thing. I suppose you could craft a regex to do the same too.

Comment: The token may not always be a link. Could be plain text (works fine) Or links with custom formatting, or an image. That's why the ideal approach is exact match.

Comment: Just a thought: could the affected machines be set to "use Word as the email editor"? I know the HTML that comes out of Word is a huge mess most times.

Comment: Yes, it's set to use Word as email editior. Which is the default, I think. Anyway, I found no  easy solution or documentation regarding this. In MSDN forums, a suggestion was made to use Word interop to replace the token and that would be too much of a complication for the simple task I'm trying to achieve. Not to mention, I'm out of time. So solution is to for me to update the token as it appears in the Word generation HTML or use a much simpler token such as a simple text.

Thank you.